# Given three chords on a circle which form an interior triangle what is the area of the triangle formed?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, geometric-probability

Using an argument similar to this one, the probability of a triangle being formed is $\frac{1}{15}$ since the [number of ways](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33712/probability-question-about-chords-on-a-circle?rq=1) six points on the circumference of a circle can be grouped into three sets of two is $\frac{6!}{2!^33!}=15$ and only one of these ways to group forms a triangle. Another way to think about this is forming all chords from six points and looking at $\triangle GKL$, the [interior triangle formed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3211897/drawing-all-chords-between-six-points-on-a-circle-prove-that-only-one-triangle).

[image]

Given a triangle is formed by three chords of a circle, what is the area of the triangle in terms of the location of the six points on the circle? I am looking run a simulation of the expected area given three random chords but having a hard time simply solving for the area of the triangle.

For simplicity I think we can assume that the circle is a unit circle of radius one?

Comment: I think it is more meaningful to think about the triangle formed by three random points on the circle.

Comment: Yes, look up Bertrand's Paradox.  There is no standard uniform distribution on chords in a circle. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)

Comment: @MatthewDaly I was imagining choosing six points uniformly on $[0,2\pi]$ and then grouping the points into the particular three sets of two which form an interior triangle.

Comment: @Goldbug Good.  That's the kind of detail that could help to determine a strategy.

Comment: @MatthewDaly Yes, but here I guess it is not really relevant that the chords are random, I am just trying to solve for the area given the six points. My motivation to solve for the area in the first place is to simulate using random chords however.

Comment: @DonThousand Indeed it is an interesting question which I am surprised has not been asked here before. I cannot seem to find it. Looking at cyclic triangles would be a special case of another [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3472691/what-is-the-expected-area-of-a-cyclic-quadrilateral-inscribed-in-a-unit-circle?rq=1) allowing two of the points to be the same? I think the area could be found in a similar fashion by using [Heron's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula) once one found the three sides using the central angles.

Comment: If the points are $(\cos\theta_i, \sin\theta_i),\ i=1,2,3$, you can use the determinant formula to get the area of the triangle.  Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @saulspatz I think one could use the [determinant formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Menger_determinant) if we had the three interior points where the three chords intersect to form the triangle?

Comment: Ah, I didn't understand what you meant by the "interior" triangle.   Are you saying then that we pair the points so that there are two points lying on either side of the resulting chord?

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks, I added a picture to make it more obvious which triangle I am referring to and interested in finding the area of.

Comment: In the picture, at least, what I said is true.  Chord $AD$ has points $B$ and $C$ on one side, and points $E$ and $F$ on the other.  Similar statements hold for the other two pink chords. This makes it easy to pick out the pairs in a computer program.

Answer (score 3):

While I think it is probably possible to compute the expected area exactly, it hardly seems worthwhile.  We can choose $6$ angles uniformly between $0$ and $2\pi$ and order them so that $$0\leq \theta_0 < \theta_i < \cdots < \theta_5 < 2\pi$$  WLOG we can take $\theta_0=0.$  Then the expected value is 
$$\frac{1}{32\pi^5}\int_0^{2\pi}\mathrm{d}\theta_1
\int_{\theta_1}^{2\pi}\mathrm{d}\theta_2
\int_{\theta_2}^{2\pi}\mathrm{d}\theta_3
\int_{\theta_3}^{2\pi}\mathrm{d}\theta_4
\int_{\theta_4}^{2\pi}A(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3,\theta_4,\theta_5)\mathrm{d}\theta_5
$$
where $A$ is a rational function of sines and cosines.  Presumably this can be integrated in closed form by making the Weierstrass substitution on each of $\theta_5, \theta_4, \dots$ in turn. I shudder at the thought, but maybe a CAS can do it.

Following Βασίλης's lead, I wrote a simulation, using a circle of radius $1$.  I consistently get a value around $.083.$  The code is given below.  I just used Βασίλης's formulas, without checking them.  You ought to do that, as well as checking my code for errors.  I used the understanding I made in the comments.  If the angles are $\theta_0, \theta_1, \dots, \theta_5$ in cyclic order, then the chords connect $\theta_i$ and $\theta_{i+3}$ for $i=1,2,3.$

```
from math import sin, cos, pi, sqrt
from random import random
import numpy as np

trials = 100000

def area():
    theta = sorted(2*pi*random() for _ in range(6))
    A = [sin(theta[i]) - sin(theta[i+3]) for i in range(3)]
    B = [cos(theta[i+3]) - cos(theta[i]) for i in range(3)]
    C = [-sin(theta[i])*B[i]-cos(theta[i])*A[i] for i in range(3)]
    D = [A[i]*B[(i+1)%3]-A[(i+1)%3]*B[i] for i in range(3)]
    Dx = [-B[i]*C[(i+1)%3]+B[(i+1)%3]*C[i] for i in range(3)]
    Dy = [-A[i]*C[(i+1)%3]+A[(i+1)%3]*C[i] for i in range(3)]
    x = [Dx[i]/D[i] for i in range(3)]
    y =  [Dy[i]/D[i] for i in range(3)]
    M = np.ones((3,3))
    M[0,:] = x
    M[1,:] = y
    return .5*abs(np.linalg.det(M))

total = 0
squares = 0
for _ in range(trials):
    a = area()
    total += a
    squares += a*a
mean = total/trials
var = squares/trials - mean*mean
print(f'{trials} trials')
print(f'Mean: {mean}') 
print(f'Std deviation {sqrt(var)}')
```

Typical output:

```
100000 trials
Mean: 0.08274184243163976
Std deviation 0.12692829789994378
```

Answer (score 2):

An analytic approach:

The six points you have at hand form three lines with equations (supposing they form a triangle, this is indeed true):

$$\begin{align}
A_1x+B_1y+C_1&=0,\\
A_2x+B_2y+C_2&=0,\\
A_3x+B_3y+C_3&=0,
\end{align}$$

where $|A_i|+|B_i|>0$. Now, solving the following systems (all do have a unique solution since the three lines form a triangle and, hence, intersect pairwise each other):

$$S_1=\left\{\begin{array}{l}
A_ix+B_iy+C_i=0,\\
A_jx+B_jy+C_j=0\end{array}\right.,
$$
where $j=i+1\mod3$ and $i=1,2,3$. Let $X_1,X_2,X_3$ be these points with cordinates:

$$x_i=\frac{D_i^x}{D_i},y_i=\frac{D_i^y}{D_i},$$

where $D_i=A_iB_j-A_jB_i$, $D_i^x=-B_iC_j+B_jC_i$ and $D_i^y=-A_iC_j+A_jC_i$, with $i=1,2,3$ and $j$ as above.

Now that you have the triangle's endpoints, it is easy to find its area e.g. using the determinant formula:
$$E=\frac{1}{2}\left|\vec{X_1X_2},\vec{X_2X_3}\right|$$

Comment: In the case of $n=2$ the [determinant formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Menger_determinant) and [Heron's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula) are equivalent, giving the area in terms of the sides. Ideally, it might be simpler to describe the points in radial coordinates with the center of the circle at 0 and possibly even radius 1 since we could scale the triangle. I wonder if there is a way to describe the sides in terms of the radial coordinates of the points? However, I think your approach is definitely valid.

Comment: Well, for radial coordinates, you could shift the last formula's coordinates to radial, however, I feel this is more messy than worth it! :P